# Using Sharepoint Designer to create custom forms for each content type in a list - Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016, custom-form

I have a list containing two separate content types - lets call them A and B

I want to have custom display forms, so that when a user clicks on an item they see appropriately formatted data.

In Sharepoint designer I can create a form and assign it to A and do the same for B. But I can't make the new form the default for just its own content type.

There's a 'make this the default form' button, but this makes it the default for **both** content types. Has anyone got any ideas?

I've found this old question:

[Custom Form per Content Type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131321/custom-form-per-content-type)

But I'm baffled by what it is attempting to do, and I've never used PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify links to forms separately for each content type in SharePoint Designer. Just select a list, navigate to a content type in the lower-left corner and setup links to custom forms:
[image]